# A study in scarlet

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

What is the meaning of following sentenece
"**as free as an income of eleven shillings and sixpence permit a man to be**

Comment: The implication is that his income is quite small, and it limits his freedom. For example if his expenditure is also eleven shillings and sixpence, then he is not free to spend money going to the theatre, and if his expenditure is eleven shillings, then he might be free to go to the theatre, but not to Paris.

Answer (score 2):

"The law, in its majestic equality, forbids rich and poor alike to sleep under bridges, to beg in the streets, and to steal their bread." - Anatole France

The rich and poor are also equally free to travel abroad, have extended holidays, or buy a yacht - in the sense that they have the same formal rights and the poor are not prohibited by law from doing these things.

However, in practical terms the poor have less freedom because they lack the means to exercise their freedom.

So earning only a limited wage (such as eleven shillings and sixpence) affects how free a person really is in practice.